# Neosemantics unexpected character

Tags: encoding, neo4j, rdf

I'm importing Turtle files into Neo4j with the Neosemantics plugin.
However, I'm getting an error with the fetch() function.
It says "Unexpected character U+1056D6 at index 32", and I think it's an encoding error (maybe I should use UTF-32?)
How do I change encoding settings for Neosemantics or ignore this error? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: `U+100000` to `U+10FFFD`  is *Plane 16 **Private Use*** range…

Comment: Hmm, so I guess it's better to filter these characters.

Comment: Hi @Zixin, did you find a workaround to this?